# Securely pass credentials to conda to access corporate proxy channels

Tags: conda, nexus, credentials, miniconda

*Not sure this actually belongs to SO, please indicate a more suitable community if any...*

I'm trying to access `conda` repositories through a corporate proxy hosted by Nexus OSS, from a Windows 10 workstation. The connection works fine but requires the user to store their credentials in the `.condarc` file:

```
channels
 - https://<user>:<password>@<my_corp_proxy>/<repo1>/
 - https://<user>:<password>@<my_corp_proxy>/<repo2>/
```

Not only is the password stored unencrypted in the file: it is prompted to the user whenever there is an error, and in a more tricky fashion, it is also stored in the `.json` file reporting the package download in the environment `conda-meta` directory. This is a [known issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6969) in `conda`.

I feel **very** uncomfortable about having to store my password in plain sight, especially as we're using LDAP authentication. **I'm looking for a way to ask conda to retrieve credentials in a more secure way**, but until now, upon my numerous researches on the internet, I failed to find any.

I have tried to store my credentials in *Windows Credential Manager*, within the *Generic Credentials* section. `git:https://<corporate-gitlab-server>` seems to work for git (was added by git at first connection), so I tried the following for conda:

```
conda:https://<corporate-nexus-repo>
miniconda3:https://<corporate-nexus-repo>
python:https://<corporate-nexus-repo>
```

None of the above configurations seems to be understood by `conda`. So here we are:

- **How should I store my credentials in Windows Credential Manager**, in order for `conda` to retrieve them? I didn't find any detailed documentation on how to use this feature.
- If this is not possible, **is there any easily feasable workaround** (this should be something all end users can manage in a reasonable number of steps)?

Comment: FYI, the NXRM3 user tokens allows you to store passwords not in plaintext.  It's a professional feature however.  Not an answer to you, but may help if you get boxed in.

Answer (score 0):

[Windows GCM](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) (Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) allows for caching the credentials used by Git to access a remote repository: that would not work for other type of remote services (like a corporate proxy).

At work, we always use a local proxy (which redirect to the actual corporate proxy, using the credentials of the current session): [**genotrance/px**](https://github.com/genotrance/px) (there is a [`px.exe` pre-compiled for Windows](https://github.com/genotrance/px/releases))

> Px is a HTTP(s) proxy server that allows applications to authenticate through an NTLM or Kerberos proxy server, typically used in corporate deployments, without having to deal with the actual handshake.
>
> It is primarily designed to run on Windows systems and authenticates on behalf of the application using the currently logged in Windows user account.

That way, no credentials is ever stored locally.

---

The [OP Romain Reboulleau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9709105/romain-reboulleau) chose another approach [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60672233/securely-pass-credentials-to-conda-to-access-corporate-proxy-channels/60710196#comment107893113_60710196):

> The platform management team removed the need to authenticate to download from the repo.
> So now credentials are only required for repository managers, who use another client, and this one does not need the credentials to be stored.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am looking for a solution which would not require the user to perform too many actions, as this would have to be done by every end user. The installation and configuration process seems complicated to me. What is interesting, though, is that this solution appears to use Windows credential manager as backend. So there must be a way.

Comment: @RomainReboulleau I can assure you, the "installation and configuration process seems complicated to me" is dead simple. The px.ini includes the name and port of your proxy, the rest are the default value.

Comment: OK, I'll try that. If it does work, maybe I'll try to package it for the users.

Comment: Something did happen in the credential manager, but I was not able to make the client use it. I think the problem is on the client side. Anyway, the platform management team removed the need to authenticate to download from the repo. So now credentials are only required for repository managers, who use another client, and this one does not need the credentials to be stored.

Comment: @RomainReboulleau OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.